# php strangely nested key/value array - how to transform/map to be more usable?

Tags: php, arrays, json, azure-qna-maker

The Microsoft QnAMaker API is returning a JSON key/value array (`Metadata`) in the following format:

```
$array = [[
    "name" => "someName1",
    "value" => "someValue1",
],
[
    "name" => "someName2",
    "value" => "someValue2",
],
 ..etc..
];
```

How do i transform it to be in the following more usable format:

```
$array = [
    "someName1" => "someValue1",
    "someName2" => "someValue2",
    ..etc..
];
```

I know I can do it using a loop... Is there a way to leverage on built in functions?

If a loop is the only way, how would you write it and why (performance/readibility/etc.)?

Comment: Could you not simply store `$array[0][0]` in a temp variable and then remove the second index --> `$array[0][0]` --  then set `$array[0]` ?

Comment: @Zak - not sure what you mean...

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just use a loop? It's only like 3 lines

Comment: @Leo after looking at it more closely, what you are asking is a little more complicated as far as restructuring your array --  You are trying to use key **values** as key  **identifiers**  -- This is going to require a loop .. There's just no other way around it.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - loop is ok... i just wondered if there was something i could leverage on... I was hoping for someone more fluent in PHP to show me a double filter and combine solution or thereabout...

Comment: I stand corrected .. Nigel's answer appears to be correct.

Comment: Sounds like what you're thinking of is flatmap. PHP doesn't have that built-in. Other folks have created their own: https://gist.github.com/davidrjonas/8f820ab0c75534b45189eba1d1fbeb23 ... which is effectively what has been posted already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it looks JSONish, [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) helps.  Simply:

```
<?php
var_export(array_column($array, 'value', 'name'));
```

Output:

```
array (
    'someName1' => 'someValue1',
    'someName2' => 'someValue2',
)
```

Comment: Nice solution, I didn't know you could pass 3 variables to `array_column()` like that.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton  I did, and yet it took more than a while to come back to me.  You can get a long way with some simple constructs such as a foreach.  I'm always going back to the manual for array function lookups (blushes)..

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a way besides a loop, so just loop through the array, and create a new array the way you need it.

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($array as $row) {
    $new_array[$row['name']] = $row['value'];
}

print_r($new_array);
```

There may be a few functions you can tie together to do what you want, but in general, the loop would probably be more readable and easier in overall.

Comment: It's a much simpler way of doing it and more maintainable IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

This uses a combination of `array_map()` to re-map each element and then `array_merge()` to flatten the results...

```
print_r(array_merge(...array_map(function($data) 
                         { return [ $data['name'] => $data['value']]; }
                       , $array)));
```

It's not very elegant and would be interesting to see other ideas around this.

Which gives...

```
Array
(
    [someName1] => someValue1
    [someName2] => someValue2
)
```

Comment: This would produce `Array
(
    [someName1] => someName2
    [someValue1] => someValue2
)`

Comment: @Zak, thanks - I've altered the code and actually checked the results this time.

Comment: `...array_map` - sorry i'm new to php... what does `...` in front of function do?

Comment: The ... (also called the splat operator) passes each element from an array as a parameter.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia It unpacks all the variables returned from array_map as a separate parameter

Comment: @Leo  --  It's called a "splat" operator https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator

Comment: This is genius... But it looks like i am better of with a loop. Thank you though.

Comment: Anyone else maintaining your code will thank you for going with a loop :)

Answer (score 2):

As my previous answer was a dupe of GrumpyCroutons, I thought I'd rewrite with many array functions for good measure.  (But don't use this, just do a simple foreach).

```
<?php
array_walk($array, function($v) use (&$result) {
    $result[array_shift($v)] = array_values($v)[0];
});

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'someName1' => 'someValue1',
  'someName2' => 'someValue2',
)
```

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton et al, hold your horses, I hadn't seen any answers when posting.

Comment: This is a good and valid answer - but I would note that [`array_walk()` may not necessarily be faster than `foreach()`](http://www.ktorides.com/2015/02/php-array_walk-vs-foreach/) (Also, since this is a good and valid answer, I gave you an upvote to balance out that downvote you got when your answer was a duplicate)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I would say valid, but not good, rather ugly.  I do note that a simple foreach would be preferable and dare I say, the _pythonic_ way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$res = [];
array_walk($array, function(&$e) use(&$res) {
    $res[$e['name']] = $e['value'];
    unset($e); // this line adds side effects and it could be deleted
});
var_dump($res);
```

Output:

```
array(2) { 
   ["someName1"]=> string(10) "someValue1" 
   ["someName2"]=> string(10) "someValue2" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use array_reduce:

```
<?php
$output = array_reduce($array, function($a, $b) {
    $a[$b['name']] = $b['value'];

    return $a;
});

var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'someName1' => 'someValue1',
    'someName2' => 'someValue2',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

While getting a shift on (a non-foreach):

```
<?php
$c = $array;
while($d = array_shift($c))
    $e[array_shift($d)] = array_shift($d);

var_export($e);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'someName1' => 'someValue1',
    'someName2' => 'someValue2',
)
```

Although it suggests in the comments in the manual that shifting is more expensive than popping.  You could replace the initial assignment to $c above with an array_reverse and the while-shift with a while-pop.

However, either approach is probably lousy compared to a foreach, but here for who knows whos amusement.